# GridView getChildAt returning null for visible children

Tags: android, gridview

I have a grid of images that were taken from a custom camera activity.
On other activity I load the images into a grid.
I have a method that turn on & off a checkbox on each Image.
While trying to move through all the images, I'm getting some strange behavior:
GridView.getCount() returns the correct number of images in the GridView, but GridView.getChildAt() method returned only part of the images.
so, when I try to do so, I get a null Exception.

## The GridView Adapter:

```
public class PhotoGalleryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    // Declare variables
    private Activity adapterActivity;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList gridItemsArray;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public PhotoGalleryAdapter(Activity a, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList fGridItemArray) {
        super(a, layoutResourceId, fGridItemArray);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.adapterActivity = a;
        this.gridItemsArray = fGridItemArray;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return gridItemsArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return gridItemsArray.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HolderViewRow holderRow = null;
        View rowView = (View) convertView;

        if (rowView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = adapterActivity.getLayoutInflater();

            rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holderRow = new HolderViewRow();

            holderRow.imageFileBMP = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageObject);

            holderRow.checkBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            holderRow.checkBoxImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemImageCheckBox);

            rowView.setTag(holderRow);
        }
        else
        {
            holderRow = (HolderViewRow) rowView.getTag();
        }

        PhotoGalleryItem item = (PhotoGalleryItem) gridItemsArray.get(position);

        // Set the decoded bitmap iitemnto ImageView
        holderRow.imageFileBMP.setImageBitmap(item.getImageBMP());
        holderRow.imageFilePath = item.getImagePath();

        return rowView;
    }

    static class HolderViewRow {
        ImageView imageFileBMP;
        String imageFilePath;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageView checkBoxImage;
    }
}


public class PhotoGalleryItem {
    private Bitmap imageBMP;
    private String imagePath;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private ImageView checkBoxImage;

    public PhotoGalleryItem(Bitmap imageBMP, String imagePath) {
        super();
        this.imageBMP = imageBMP;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public Bitmap getImageBMP() {
        return imageBMP;
    }

    public void setImageBMP(Bitmap imageBMP) {
        this.imageBMP = imageBMP;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
```

## The Grid Activity:

```
        private void RenderGridAndSetImages() {
            // Locate the GridView in gridView_PhotoDisplay.xml
            gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_PhotoDisplay);
            // Pass String arrays to Adapter Class
            imageAdapter = new PhotoGalleryAdapter(this, R.layout.gridview_photo_item, GridItemArrayList);
            gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
```

## And the function that has the problem:

```
    public void SetVisibilityCheckBox_OnGrid (boolean checkBoxVisibility) {
        // Handle item selection On GRIDVIEW ImageItem
        final int size = gridView.getCount();
        try {
            ImageView imageCB;
            int cbVisibility;

            if (checkBoxVisibility)
                cbVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
            else
                cbVisibility = View.INVISIBLE;

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                View viewItem = (View) gridView.getChildAt(i);
                if (viewItem != null) {
                    imageCB = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.itemImageCheckBox);
                    imageCB.setVisibility(cbVisibility);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Error occurred while SetSelectCheckBoxOnGrid
            Log.e(PACKAGE_NAME, ACTIVITY_NAME + ".SetVisibilityCheckBox_OnGrid\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

## The GridView Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_Holder"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/activityBackground"
    tools:context="com.mountain.saymera.PhotoGalleryActivity">

    <!-- Image view: layout_GridView -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_PhotoGridDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/activityBackground"
        android:padding="1dp">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView_PhotoDisplay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_NoImages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gallery_no_images"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textColor="@color/MenuButtonTint"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## The GridView Item Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_Holder"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/single_photo_frame_on_grid">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/Grid_ItemFrame"
        android:padding="0.3dp">

        <com.mountain.saymera.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageObject"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:tint="@color/Grid_ItemCheckbox"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImageCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_crop_square_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/MenuCheckboxTint"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Need some help, Thanks

Comment: please add crash logs

Comment: Thanks, The application doesn't crash, so there are no errors on the log. there are 48 images that are displayed on the grid, but the GridView.getChildAt() has access just to the first  28 items, other items returns null. I don't no if it has something with the problem but  I have noticed that when the items are displayed on the screen GridView.getChildAt() returns the Items, but when I have to scroll down to other images, those are the images that return null.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with programatically added ImageViews in a LinearLayout. Unfortunately, this method seems to be buggy at the moment, so I had to help myself by finding an alternative.
As a workaround, I saved the references of my ImageViews in a List and worked with them.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, since it doesn't actually answer the question